# Global transaction event handling in Micronaut 3

Tags: kotlin, event-handling, aop, micronaut, micronaut-data

I want to register a global transaction before commit event handler on Application startup. What is the best way to do this?

I tried @TransactionalEventListener annotation but this requires a call to be done to this method inside every transaction. I want to register a global handler.

Edit:
I have found a working solution but still am wondering if there is something simpler.

My solution:

```
@Primary
@Order(Int.MIN_VALUE)
@EachBean(DataSource::class)
@TypeHint(DataSourceTransactionManager::class)
class AuditedDataSourceTransactionManager(
    dataSource: DataSource
) : DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource) {
    override fun doCommit(status: DefaultTransactionStatus<*>?) {
        if (status?.isReadOnly == false) {
            // do my stuff
        }
        super.doCommit(status)
    }
}
```